# Speed up -drawRect: method for UIView subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, drawrect

I've created a custom UIView subclass. Everything works fine on the simulator, but very slow on the device. My `-drawRect:` method takes about 100 milliseconds to fully redraw the view.

The speed problem arose when I added a pan gesture to this view and, while dragging, the view needed to be redrawn multiple times per second.

I need to optimize the drawRect: method. Here's my current `-drawRect:` method code:

```
- (void)loayoutSubviews
{
    for (UIView* subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    };

    // ...
    // some calculations here... assume that they can not be optimized
    // ...

    for (unsigned int blockCounter=0; blockCounter<blockQuantity; blockCounter++)
    {
        NSNumber *y=[blockTops objectAtIndex:blockCounter];
        NSNumber *height=[blockHeights objectAtIndex:blockCounter];

        if ([height intValue]>2)
        {
            if ([y doubleValue]>self.frame.size.height/2.0)
            {
                double angle= [[self angleValueForBlockHeight:height] doubleValue];

                UIView *bView=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[blocks objectAtIndex:blockCounter]]];
                [bView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, [y doubleValue], self.frame.size.width, blockSize.height)];
                [bView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];


                double oldHeight=bView.frame.size.height;

                [bView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
                [bView setFrame:CGRectMake(bView.frame.origin.x, bView.frame.origin.y+bView.frame.size.height/2.0, bView.frame.size.width, bView.frame.size.height)];

                if ([height doubleValue]!=blockSize.height)
                {
                    //preparing transform
                    CATransform3D basicTrans = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    basicTrans.m34 =1.0/-projection;

                    double rangle;
                    rangle=angle/360*(2.0*M_PI);

                    bView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(basicTrans, rangle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

                };



                double newHeight=bView.frame.size.height;

                [bView setCenter:CGPointMake(bView.center.x, bView.center.y-(oldHeight-newHeight))];

                //adding subview
                [self addSubview:bView];
            }
            else
            {                
                double angle= [[self angleValueForBlockHeight:height] doubleValue];

                UIView *bView=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[blocks objectAtIndex:blockCounter]]];
                [bView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, [y doubleValue], self.frame.size.width, blockSize.height)];
                [bView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

                [bView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.0)];
                [bView setFrame:CGRectMake(bView.frame.origin.x, bView.frame.origin.y-bView.frame.size.height/2.0, bView.frame.size.width, bView.frame.size.height)];

                if ([height doubleValue]!=blockSize.height)
                {
                    //preparing transform
                    CATransform3D basicTrans = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    basicTrans.m34 =1.0/-projection;

                    double rangle;
                    rangle=(360.0-angle)/360*(2.0*M_PI);

                    bView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(basicTrans, rangle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

                };

                //adding subview
                [self addSubview:bView];
            };
        }
        else
        {
            //do not need to draw blocks with very low height
        };
    };
}
```

and here's the pan gesture recognizer code:

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{        
    double translatedY = [sender translationInView:self].y;
    double delta;

    if (fabs(translatedY)<fabs(oldTranslatedY))
    {
        [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
        oldTranslatedY=0.0;
        delta=0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        delta=translatedY-oldTranslatedY;
        oldTranslatedY=translatedY;
    };

    double pOffset=delta/((blockQuantity*blockSize.height)-self.frame.size.height);

    self.scrollPosition=self.scrollPosition-pOffset;

    if (self.scrollPosition<0.0)
    {
        self.scrollPosition=0.0;
    }
    else if(self.scrollPosition>1.0)
    {
        self.scrollPosition=1.0;
    };

    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Please feel free to ask me any questions.

**UPDATED: moved code from drawRect: method to layoutSubviews**

Comment: You shouldn't be doing view layout in drawRect, I'd recommend doing it in layoutSubviews

Comment: Im not sure why you use the drawRect. You are creating a View and use CATransform3DRotate to do the transformation, why do you need to do this in the drawRect?

Comment: @Tom Irving, didn't reload the page yet. Sorry

Comment: I'll try to put my code to layoutSubviews method. And update my answer

Comment: moving the code from drawRect to layoutSubview haven't increased speed of redrawing.

Comment: The view itself represented by it's group of subviews. So maybe moving  code back to drawRect: and changing addSubview/removeFromSuperview code to something closer to CG will result in speeding up?

Comment: try to disable implicit animations

Comment: Please clarify what animations are you talking about? The transform code must not be disabled. Because subviews need to be drawn with perspective rotation and added to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Instruments to check which method takes most time, but I think it is unarchiving and creating of UIView. Why do you need it? Why not to hold UIView's in memory, if you need them each time.

Comment: unarchiveObjectWithData code is used for creating a copy of a view saved in memory. Then I change it's anchor point and add transformations to it

Comment: So do you need new views each time? Or you have a static set of views? And, why do you need a lot of views, why not to draw them in one drawRect: ?

Comment: OMFG!!1 That took much time. I changed that back. Now everything works fluently, but I have problems because views are retained not copied. Problems with anchor points and, probably, transform code. Could you please help me with it? Just a few code to add after the view retains from the memory to reset its anchor point and other staff

Comment: I did that staff myself. Thank you very much